# T-SQL Function to Throw error

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, exception, return

Hello there I have a Function and is introduction a variable which will bring a letter or a number, if the variable is a letter it need to cause an error and return a 0, or if is a number then return 1.

SO in T-SQL I have a Procedure that eventually will call this function to check is is a number:

```
IF  dbo.VALIDNUMBER(@sTxpX) != 0 AND @sTxpX IS NOT NULL
```

The variable @sTxpX is holding a value which is 'T' so I know it needs to return 0 from the function because is invalid to be a numeric, but Im not getting the proper function to build it, I will appreciate some help here.

```
CREATE FUNCTION DBO.VALIDNUMBER (@sTextStr VARCHAR(4000)) RETURNS  BIT AS
 BEGIN
DECLARE @bValidNumberStr BIT = 1; DECLARE @nTest BIGINT;

    SET @nTest = CAST(@sTextStr AS numeric(38, 10)) + 1;
    RETURN @bValidNumberStr;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        SET @bValidNumberStr = 0;
    RETURN @bValidNumberStr;
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this function:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[VALIDNUMBER]
(@strText VARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Return as bit
IF TRY_CAST(@strText AS NUMERIC(38,10)) IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SET @Return = 1
END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @Return = 0
END

RETURN @Return

END
```

Comment: Thank you this what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use the built-in SQL function? It's faster, and no need for you to drive yourself crazy to come up with a solution.

In your procedure do the following:

```
DECLARE @isNumber bit;

IF (ISNUMERIC(@sTextStr) = 1) 
    BEGIN 
        SET @isNumber = 1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @isNumber = 0

        RAISERROR(15600, 16, 20, 'That was not a number')
    END
```

You can pass the @isNumber variable back to the user at a later point in time.

Comment: But IsNumeric is a nearly useless function. Consider values like "1e4". That doesn't look like a number but will return 1 from IsNumeric. Or other interesting strings like "$."

Comment: @SeanLange technically, 1e4 is a valid number, hence it will return as TRUE. From the OP, it would seem that the variable passed in would be a single character alphanumeric character, hence my solution would work. Do you really think that these shortcomings in the ISNUMERIC function really render it useless? I felt as if that labeling was a bit harsh.

Comment: Perhaps if it was named something like ValueCanBeConvertedToAnyDatatypeThatIsVaguelyLikeANumber it would be better. :) Wasn't discounting your answer, I was discounting the IsNumeric function.